# Reducing the frame rate : the smooth video Issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, framerate

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQMHBPc2ZtU2VmX2s/view?usp=sharing) is my smooth video.

Video details:

Frame rate=60 FPS
Video codec: h264
Not have any audio stream

I want to convert it to a PAL video, But I can't get smooth video.

How to convert a high frame rate video to PAL format(or reducing the frame rate) Without impact on the smoothness of video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of preference,

- Generate animation at 25 FPS and capture it at 25 FPS.
- Generate animation at 50 FPS and capture it at 50 FPS. Then, use FFmpeg to generate a 25 frames & 50 fields per sec stream. Stream should be flagged as interlaced. x264 doesn't do interlaced well, so I suggest video codec ought to be MPEG-2 or DV.
- Generate animation at 50 FPS and capture it at 25 FPS.